# Inscrutable Ruby: Vector Assignment Example

Tags: ruby, programming-languages, syntax

Consider the following:

```
a=[0,1] #our starting value
a=[a,1] #=> [[0,1],1] as expected
```

I would anticipate the following to have the same result:

```
a=[0,1] #same starting place
a[0]=a  #should make a the same thing as it was above, right?
a       #=> [[...],1]   !!!
```

In the first example, the second assignment refers to the value of `a` before the assignment was made.  In the second example, the second assignment performs a recursive assignment.  This feels like different behavior to me.  Is this behavior in fact consistent?  If so can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the first example you are *creating a new array* with the value [[0,1], 1]. Then you are reassigning `a` to refer to this array.

In the second example you are not creating a new array, nor are you changing what `a` refers to. You are *changing the existing array* to contain a reference to itself. That's very different.

---

#### More details

The first example is roughly equivalent to this code:

```
a = [0, 1]  # Step 1
b = [a, 1]  # Step 2
a = b       # Step 3
```

In pictures it looks like this:

- Step 1 - create an array:

```
---
|a|
---
 |
 v
 [0, 1]
```

- Step 2 - create another array which includes a reference to the first:

```
    ---        ---
    |a|        |b| 
    ---        ---
     |          |
     |          v
     |          [ref, 1]
     |            |
     +------------+
     v 
     [0, 1]
```

- Step 3 - change `a` to point to the array created in step 2:

```
    ---        ---
    |a|        |b| 
    ---        ---
     |          |
     +----------+
                v
                [ref, 1]
                  |
    +-------------+
    v 
    [0, 1]
```

On the other hand, the code in the second example gives you this:

```
    ---
    |a|
    ---
     |
 +---+
 |   v
 |   [ref, 1]
 |     |
 +-----+
```

Here there is still only one array, and `a` still points to it. But now the first element in the array refers to the array itself.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby all variables (without exceptions) are references.

In this case `a` is a reference to Array. Kinda like `a` in `int *a` in C.

By doing `a[0] = a` you make `a` an array where the first element is reference to `a`.